# Create Formula field for the Address on the Case Object

Tags: formula

I want to create the formula field on the Case object for the HomeAddress which includes (Street, City, State, Zip, Country). The Street, City, State, Zip, Country are present on the Contact Object.

```
CASE 
( 
 Contact.MailingStreet +' '+ Contact.MailingCity +' '+ Contact.MailingState +' '+ Contact.MailingPostalCode+' '+Contact.Citizenship__c,
 CaseNumber
)
```

**I tried the above, but its giving me the following error:**

> Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'CASE()'. Expected 2, received 2

Comment: Any inputs on this ?

Comment: A CASE formula requires a conditional, and value if true, value if false. The documentation - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=0&language=en_US - reading it is usually very helpful

Answer (score 2):

The case function checks a given expression against a series of values. If the expression is equal to a value, returns the corresponding result. If it is not equal to any values, it returns the else_result.

You don't need that if you just want to combine a number of string values.

Try it without the case like this:

```
Contact.MailingStreet & ' ' & Contact.MailingCity & ' ' & Contact.MailingState & ' ' & Contact.MailingPostalCode & ' ' & Contact.Citizenship__c & ' ' &
 CaseNumber
```

If you would to add line breaks between the different values you can do that by replacing the spaces with BR()

```
Contact.MailingStreet & BR() & Contact.MailingCity & BR() & Contact.MailingState & BR() & Contact.MailingPostalCode & BR() & Contact.Citizenship__c & BR() & CaseNumber
```